# Cypress freezes after couple of seconds

Tags: cypress

I type `npx cypress open` , cypress opens, after about 40 seconds, the cypress stops responding (it freezes), can't click anything, totally non responsive, had to use force quit to quit.

Have tried clearing the cache and re-installing the cypress and not able to find solution.
Please help.

Cypress Version
10.10.1

Node version
8.15.0

Operating System
macOS 12.1

Comment: Can you try installing a Node 12+ version? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Node-js-12-support

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Node-js-12-support) Manuel is referring to show that you need to upgrade your version of Node.js to (preferably) Node.js 14.

These docs are current for Cypress v10.10.0.

> **Node.js 12+ support**
>
> Cypress comes bundled with its own Node.js version. However, installing the cypress npm package uses the Node.js version installed on your system.
>
> Node.js 10 reached its end of life on Dec 31, 2019 and Node.js 13 reached its end of life on June 1, 2019. See Node's release schedule. These Node.js versions will no longer be supported when installing Cypress. The minimum Node.js version supported to install Cypress is Node.js 12 or **Node.js 14+**.